# Align TextBlocks in a circle UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to align 12 TextBlocks in a circle like this

[image]

InOrder to achieve this I have tried something like this

```
    <Grid >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="24"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="24"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="24"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="24"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="24"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="24"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="24"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="24"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="24"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="24"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="24"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="24"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="24"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="24"></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="9" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="11" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="12" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="1" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="2" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="2"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="3" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="3"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="4" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="4"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="5" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="5"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="6" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="6"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
```

But this doesn't give me a good circle, is there any other way to achieve label arranged in a circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a good circle, the grid is not a suitable solution. Using a coordinate system in canvas might be a way to create a good circle. Let's say we need a clock whose size is 200*200. So the center point `(x0,y0)` is `(100,100)`. As we know, the angle between the two adjacent numbers is 30. Then the center point of the TextBlock for 2 o'clock- (x2, y2) can be calculated.

`x2 = x0 + r * cos(Math.PI * angle/ 180.0)`  and `y2 = y0 - r * sin(Math.PI * angle/ 180.0)`

It's the same for other TextBlocks.

**Updated**

I made a simple sample for this.

Xaml:

```
 <Canvas Background="Gray" Width="300" Height="300" >

        <TextBlock Text="2" x:Name="textblock2"  ></TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Text="1" x:Name="textblock1"  ></TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Width="20" Height="20" Text="12" Canvas.Top="40" Canvas.Left="140"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Width="20" Height="20" Text="9" Canvas.Top="140" Canvas.Left="40"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Width="20" Height="20" Text="3" Canvas.Top="140" Canvas.Left="240" ></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Width="20" Height="20" Text="6" Canvas.Top="240" Canvas.Left="140" ></TextBlock>
    </Canvas>
```

Code behind:

```
        int r = 100;

        //1 o'clock
        // need to minus 10 to get Canvas.top and Canvas.lelf value because x1 y1 represent the center of the textblock not the center of the textblock
        double x1 = 150 + r * Math.Cos(Math.PI * 60 / 180.0) - 10;
        double y1 = 150 - r * Math.Sin(Math.PI * 60 / 180.0) - 10;
        textblock1.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, x1);
        textblock1.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, y1);


        //2 o'clock
        double x2 = 150 + r * Math.Cos(Math.PI * 30 / 180.0)-10;
        double y2 = 150 - r * Math.Sin(Math.PI * 30 / 180.0)-10;
        textblock2.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, x2);
        textblock2.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, y2);
```

What it looks like:
[image]

Comment: I haven't understood this completely, can you please provide little more clarity.

Comment: @None I've updated the code snippet. Please check that.